# A question about a replacement of element of set

Tags: assignment

To begin with, I'm a poor English speaker, which means it would be hard to read to natives...
 I was trying to memorize mRNA codons with mathematica.

```
mRNA={"U","C","A","G"}
Flatten[Table[f[{X,Y,Z}],{X,mRNA},{Y,mRNA},{Z,mRNA}],2]
```

A code above is what I wrote and what I want to do is to assign a number. Ex) f[{"U","U","U"}]=1, f[{"U","U","C"}]=2 ,etc/

So I tried a code below

```
Flatten[Table[f[{X,Y,Z}],{X,mRNA},{Y,mRNA},{Z,mRNA}],2]=Range[64]
```

But it causes a Set::Write error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
MapIndexed[(f[#1]=#2[[1]])&, Tuples[mRNA, 3]]
```

On the other hand, an `Association` may be better to use:

```
A = AssociationThread[Tuples[mRNA, 3] -> Range[64]]
```

which you can then use with

```
A[{"U","U","C"}]
```

> 2

Comment: Thanks! What a nice method!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `Evaluate` around the LHS of the assignment:

```
Evaluate[Flatten[Table[f[{X, Y, Z}], {X, mRNA}, {Y, mRNA}, {Z, mRNA}], 2]] = Range[64];
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved my time.